# Crash on custom Animation Vector Drawable for Indeterminate ProgressBar

Tags: android

I wanna customize a progressbar, however the app crashed.

This is usage:

```
    <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/search_button_progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    style="@style/ProgressBar.Customized"
    />
```

This is style:

```
<style name="ProgressBar" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateBehavior">repeat</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDuration">@android:integer/config_longAnimTime</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBar.Customized">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_loading_pb_group</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/ic_animated_loading_pb</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateBehavior">cycle</item>
</style>
```

This is drawable/ic_loading_pb_group:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="50dp"
    android:height="50dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">


<group
    android:name="rotation_group"
    android:pivotX="12"
    android:pivotY="12"
    android:rotation="0" >

    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/new_blue"
        android:pathData="M13,2.05v3.03c3.39,0.49 6,3.39 6,6.92 0,0.9 -0.18,1.75 -0.48,2.54l2.6,1.53c0.56,-1.24 0.88,-2.62 0.88,-4.07 0,-5.18 -3.95,-9.45 -9,-9.95zM12,19c-3.87,0 -7,-3.13 -7,-7 0,-3.53 2.61,-6.43 6,-6.92V2.05c-5.06,0.5 -9,4.76 -9,9.95 0,5.52 4.47,10 9.99,10 3.31,0 6.24,-1.61 8.06,-4.09l-2.6,-1.53C16.17,17.98 14.21,19 12,19z"/>


</group>
```

This drawable/ic_animated_loading_pb:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading_pb_group" >
<target
    android:name="rotation_group"
    android:animation="@animator/rotation" />

</animated-vector>
```

Comment: Did you find the solution? If not you should add the crash error.

Comment: add the crash log for identify the problem